# How to use join function for creating a csv file if some fields contain additional commas

Tags: perl, perl-module

I need to write a CSV file where **some of the fields contain additional commas**.

So i used  `my @fields = Text::ParseWords::parse_line(',', 0, $line); 
in order to do the processing.

But how to use join function at the end to write to a file in perl?

Comment: There is a loose standard for CSV files, [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).  It includes these kinds of cases, and is fairly readable.  It won't write your perl program for you. It might be helpful to include RFC 4180 in a google or cpan search to help you search for a perl module that complies with standards.

Comment: Could you please suggest the library module which can be used for these kinds in perl?

Comment: if you are having a problem with only comma(,) hence do you replace the something else instead of comma(,) before your "some processing". Means: =~/,/[x[y]x]/gs; or =~/,/&comma;/gs; whatever it may be. Then creating the output your will replace the comma instead of the value.

Comment: [This](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=678257) was the first google link for "CSV perl RFC4180".  It mentions a library.  Are you unable to use google in your country?

Comment: As I understand, RFC4180 (thanks for that link, though) recommends to use double quotes for field values with a commas (`"value,of,a,single,field"`). You should apply this to your output CSV. However, if your input CSV has field values with commas you could perhaps guess the right column ends by comparing field lengths and data types. Another approach would be to use another character (e.g. semicolon) to seperate the values. But that is not a solution since values could still contain semicolons.

Comment: Joining with `","` is a useful trick, if you add an extra `"` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used Text::CSV_XS->Combine function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use a CSV library such as [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.12/CSV_XS.pm).

If the only problem is extra commas in fields, and not extra quotes, there is a trick I will share.

`$line_out = '"'.join('","', @fields).'"'`

RFC4180 says to quote fields, i.e. `"field1","field2","compound,field"` , when fields may contain commas, newlines, and such.